# Доработка дерева С++

Tags: дерево, c++

Простите за создание новой темы, но в прошлой уже комментировать некуда и много всего написано,а мне уже сегодня сдавать и надо немного совсем доделать. Проблема в том, что у меня не выходит передать в мою функцию узлы с глубиной х. Задание: По заданным значениям "х" рассчитать число всех узлов с глубиной "х" в заданном дереве. то есть вопрос по передаче этого значения этим функциям. Значения там понятно как в функции задаются, а вот глубины не поняла..Объясните пожалуйста, остальное я уже поняла как делать, а вот это никак не пойму.

Функции которым я передаю:

```
void sumx (Node *Tree, int x[], int nx ) 
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
          cout << "level: " << x[i] << ' ' << cntx(Tree, x[i]) << "Nodes\n";
    }
    int cntx (Node *Tree, int deep) 
    {
       if (!Tree || deep < 0) return 0;
       if (deep == 0) return 1; 
       return cntx(Tree->l, --deep) + cntx(Tree->r, --deep);
    }

весь код:

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node 
{
   int x; 
   Node *l,*r;
};

void show(Node *&Tree) 
{
    if (Tree!=NULL)
    {
       show(Tree->l); 
       cout<<Tree->x; 
       show(Tree->r); 
    }
     cout << Tree->x << " [" << Tree << " left: " << Tree->l << " right: " << Tree->r << "]\n";
}

void add_node(int x,Node *&MyTree) 
 {
    if (MyTree) 
    {
   if (x < MyTree->x)
      add_node(x, MyTree->l);
   else
      add_node(x, MyTree->r); 
 } else {
    MyTree=new Node; 
    MyTree->x=x; 
    MyTree->l=MyTree->r=NULL; 
 }
}
void sumx (Node *Tree, int x[], int nx ) 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
      cout << "level: " << x[i] << ' ' << cntx(Tree, x[i]) << "Nodes\n";
}
int cntx (Node *Tree, int deep) 
{
   if (!Tree || deep < 0) return 0;
   if (deep == 0) return 1; 
   return cntx(Tree->l, --deep) + cntx(Tree->r, --deep);
}
void DeleteTree(Node *Tree)
{
     if (Tree)
     {
           DeleteTree(Tree->l);
           DeleteTree(Tree->r);
           delete Tree;
           Tree = NULL;
     }
}
int main()
{
   Node *Tree=NULL;  
  int z,k;
  cin >> z;
      for (int i=0;i<z;i++) 
      {
          cin >> k;
          add_node(k,Tree);
      }

      show(Tree);

       DeleteTree(Tree);
      cin.get();
      getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[[@Lera_E](/users/14832/lera_e)](/users/14832/lera_e), если откровенно, не понимаю чего  тут объяснять.

Вот по сути Ваш код (чуть правлен под Linux) и результаты запуска.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat tttx.cpp
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node 
{
   int x; 
   Node *l,*r;
};

void show(Node *&Tree) 
{
    if (Tree!=NULL)  {
      show(Tree->l); 
      //      cout<<Tree->x; 
      cout << Tree->x << " [" << Tree << " left: " << Tree->l << " right: " << Tree->r << "]\n";
      show(Tree->r); 
    }
}

void add_node(int x,Node *&MyTree)  {
  if (MyTree) 
    {
      if (x < MyTree->x)
        add_node(x, MyTree->l);
      else
        add_node(x, MyTree->r); 
    } else {
    MyTree=new Node; 
    MyTree->x=x; 
    MyTree->l=MyTree->r=NULL; 
  }
}

int cntx (Node *Tree, int deep) 
{
   if (!Tree || deep < 0) return 0;
   if (deep == 0) return 1; 
   return cntx(Tree->l, --deep) + cntx(Tree->r, --deep);
}

void sumx (Node *Tree, int x[], int nx ) 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
      cout << "level: " << x[i] << ' ' << cntx(Tree, x[i]) << " Nodes\n";
}

void DeleteTree(Node *Tree)
{
  if (Tree) {
      DeleteTree(Tree->l);
      DeleteTree(Tree->r);
      delete Tree;
  }
}

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  Node *Tree=NULL;  
  int z,k;
  cin >> z;
  for (int i=0;i<z;i++) {
    cin >> k;
    add_node(k,Tree);
  }

  show(Tree);

  for (int i = 0; i < ac; i++)
    cout << "level: " << atoi(av[i]) << ' '
         << cntx(Tree, atoi(av[i])) << " Nodes\n";

  int x[] = {1, 3, 5, 15};
  cout << "Again show number of nodes for levels\n";
  sumx(Tree, x, 4);

  cout << "All Tree levels cnt nodes\n";
  int n;
  for (int i = 0; n = cntx(Tree, i); i++)
    cout << n << " nodes on level " << i << '\n';

  DeleteTree(Tree);

  return 0;
}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ tttx.cpp
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
10 2 30 4 50 22 34 1 23 12 8
1 [0x254a0d0 left: 0 right: 0]
2 [0x254a010 left: 0x254a0d0 right: 0x254a030]
4 [0x254a050 left: 0 right: 0x254a090]
8 [0x254a130 left: 0 right: 0]
12 [0x254a110 left: 0x254a130 right: 0]
22 [0x254a090 left: 0x254a110 right: 0x254a0f0]
23 [0x254a0f0 left: 0 right: 0]
30 [0x254a030 left: 0x254a050 right: 0x254a070]
34 [0x254a0b0 left: 0 right: 0]
50 [0x254a070 left: 0x254a0b0 right: 0]
level: 0 1 Nodes
level: 1 1 Nodes
level: 2 1 Nodes
level: 3 1 Nodes
level: 4 1 Nodes
level: 5 2 Nodes
level: 6 1 Nodes
level: 7 2 Nodes
level: 8 0 Nodes
level: 9 0 Nodes
level: 10 0 Nodes
Again show number of nodes for levels
level: 1 1 Nodes
level: 3 1 Nodes
level: 5 2 Nodes
level: 15 0 Nodes
All Tree levels cnt nodes
1 nodes on level 0
1 nodes on level 1
1 nodes on level 2
1 nodes on level 3
1 nodes on level 4
2 nodes on level 5
1 nodes on level 6
2 nodes on level 7
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Расписал вывод количества узлов по уровням даже тремя разными способами.